# django-mssql on debian linux

Tags: debian, django-pyodbc, django-mssql

Anyone has success on install django-mssql on linux machine? My deploy server is debian linux and I cant deploy my applications made on windows machine.

I have troubes on my legacy latin1 database on acess it from pyodbc on django, Anyone has a solve to it?

Answer (score 1):

Pywin32 is a requirement. I don't believe there is a way of getting that installed and working on debian linux.

[Django-mssql requirements](http://django-mssql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Actually,there is a workaround with ODBC interface.

1. Install [Microsoft ODBC Driver 1.0 for linux](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160)
2. Install [django_pyodbc](https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/tree/master/django_pyodbc).
3. Configure your database backend with django-pyodbc.

I've tested,everything works just fine.