# Linux + Django + SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, django, centos

I am writing a Django application which needs to intereact with a SQLServer Database. I use the [Django MSSQL Backend ADO](http://django-mssql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

I am trying to use it in a Linux machine (CentOS 6.4), but for the moment I am not able to establish the connection.

Anyone has suceeded on it or knows if it is possible to connect to django-mssql from a Linux environment?

Note: I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004801/django-mssql-on-debian-linux) but it is quite old. I am looking for an up-to-date answer.

Edit: The error I am receiving is the following. Remark that it is a Linux machine.

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sqlserver_ado' isn't an available database backend.`

Edit 2: [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) is a requirement for the django-mssql package. But is possible any workaround for Linux?

Comment: Please post the exact error you're facing

Comment: Do you have django-mssql installed? Can you import sqlserver_ado from Django shell?

Comment: I have django-mssql installed. But nott sqlserver_ado, as it's part of the PyWin32 suite and, to my knowledge, it is not available for Linux.

Comment: If you've read the django mssql documentation, the package is called django mssql but the module is named sqlserver_ado. Recheck of you have it installed.

Comment: I will sugget to use https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure to connect to MS SQL Server. right now i am using it with django 2.0 and SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 7):

Django-MSSQL only works on Windows, hence the pywin32 dependency (Actually, anything ADO is Windows dependent since it's built on Microsoft's ActiveX).

Try [Django-SQLServer](https://github.com/denisenkom/django-sqlserver).  It's based on Django-MSSQL but can pass info using [python-tds](https://github.com/denisenkom/pytds) which is not platform specific.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use [django-pyodbc-azure](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pyodbc-azure) instead of Django-MSSQL

1. Supports Django 2.0.3
2. Supports Microsoft SQL Server 2008/2008R2, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and Azure SQL Database
3. Compatible with Micosoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server, SQL Server
   Native Client, and FreeTDS ODBC drivers